# How to format an array in a method to return on separate lines without brackets

Tags: java

I'm working on a toString method that takes in a name of a Array and returns the name and the "tasks" stored within the array. However, I'm unsure of how to format the array within the method in order to get it to print each index of the array on separate lines.

What I have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ToDoList implements ToDoListInterface {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Task> tasks;

    public ToDoList (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    }
    public String toString(String name) 
    {
        return "-------------" + "\n" + name + "\n" + "-------------" + "\n" + tasks;
    }
```

What it results:

```
-------------
To Do List
-------------
[[X]Finish studying, 0, [ ]Last minute cramming, 20, [ ]Finish studying, 0, [ ]Finish studying, 0]
```

What it's supposed to look like:

```
-------------
My ToDo List
-------------
[X] Finish studying, 0

[ ] Last minute cramming, 20

etc......
```

Comment: you mean ... iterate over the list and print the elements?

Comment: You're relying on the default `toString` of an `ArrayList`, which is not what you want. You need to iterate and collect the results. Then you need to decide if you want to rely on the default `toString` of your `Task` class as well.

Comment: Ill try that Dave

Answer (score 0):

As @Dave Newton already mentioned, you will have to iterate through your `tasks`.

**Possible Solution**:

```java
public String toString(String name) {
    String ret = "-------------" + "\n" + name + "\n" + "-------------" + "\n";

    for(Task t: tasks) {
        ret += "[" + (t.isFinished() == true ? "X" + : " ") + "] " + t.getTitle() + ", " + task.getDuration()  + "\n";
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: With tweaking from some other methods, your explanation worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why didn't you delegate some work to the `toString` method of class `Task`?

Comment: I don`t exactly know the use-case of this scenario, but I didn`t delegate it, because I wouldn`t use `.toString` to display information to the user. 
As mentioned in [this article](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073619/java-tostring---considerations.html) the `toString`-method should display the information of the ´Object`:

> When practical, the toString method should return all of the interesting information contained in the object.